# Multiple queries in mongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, gtfs

I would like to query multiple collections in mongodb, I have some data like this

```
Collection stops {
    { stop_id : 1, stop_name: 'a'},
    { stop_id : 2, stop_name: 'b'}, ...

Collection stop_time {
    { stop_id : 1, trip_id: 40},
    { stop_id : 2, trip_id: 41}, ...

Collection trips {
    { trip_id : 40, route_id: 400},
    { trip_id : 41, route_id: 401}, ...

Collection route {
    { route_id : 400, route_name: 'foo'},
    { route_id : 401, route_name: 'bar'}, ...
```

And for each stop_name, I would like to know the route_name that match with it... (I didn't chose he data-structure by the way, that's GTFS format...)

Is there a way to easily do a queries that respond to my problem?

Thanks

Comment: client side processing of data through querying the collections individually to garnish your data.

Comment: In fact, I want to add in the stops collection the route_name which match with the stop_name ...

Comment: MongoDB is NoSQL and it has no relational attributes, the only way to do JOINs is to do it client side. Unless you mean something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such approach is not good for mongodb.You should create one collection that contains all data, and make only one query.

This is very important because:

1. There is no transactions
2. There is no joins
3. There are only atomic operations on one document
4. You will be not able to use aggregation framework

If it is inpossible to migrate to one collection schema then probably you should do as below:

```
    var _ = require("underscore")._;
    function get_all(cb) {
        stops.find({}, function(err, stps, cb) {

            stop_time.find({}, function(err, stptime) {

                var all = _.map(stps, function(e) {
                    e.trip_id = stptime[e.stop_id].trip_id;
                    return e;
                });

                trips.find({}, function(err, trips) {

                    all = _.map(all, function(e) {
                        e.route_id = trips[e.trip_id].route_id;
                        return e;
                    });

                    route.find({}, function(err, routes) {

                        all = _.map(all, function(e) {
                            e.route_name = routes[e.route_id].route_name;
                            return e;
                        });

                        cb(all)
                    });
                });

            });
        });
    }
```

Be carefully, if there is a large amount of data in DB then you probably should use Cursors. http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#querystream_QueryStream

Comment: "You should create one collection that contains all data, and make only one query." embedding comes down to scenario, it is not always good practice to embed, it relies on more than what the OP has given also he didn't choose the schema so he can't change it.

Comment: You're right. It isn't always the best solution. But I think that in this situation is better to use embedding. Also he didn't say that he can't change db schema

Comment: The OP said "I didn't chose he data-structure by the way, that's GTFS format..." which most likely means he gets it from an external app. In this situation it depends upon the actual data and the queries he makes, basically if he were to supply a plan of queries he wants to make and some other info, maybe, I could give an answer on that; atm all we know is he wants to do joins

Comment: Yes.. I would like to do join... but I can't with mongodb... The fact is, I will do this operation only one time. So the time it takes to do it is not so important. And yes I have a large amount of data.. for example the stop_time collection has more than 588 000 objects...

Comment: Then you should use QueryStream. First of all create indexes on stop_id, trip_id, route_id (2,3,4 collections). Algorithm will be a little bit different. You are getting one by one element from first collection. Than do same thing as previous but each time only for one element=)

Comment: Exactly, you can also build a range query to get all rows out of each collection at same time then match them up client side, this is what JOINs do basically server side, this is why many NoSQL advocates don't really see the point in joins because when you start getting into serious amounts of data they just don't scale too well on server side, this client method scales better normally with the right queries.

Comment: Oh ok I will try that, I also thought about making a loop with the first collection elements, make a query on the second collections, and with the result make another query on the third collection and finally do the last query and get the result. Is that could work?

Comment: As i said before use QueryStream to make loop with the first collection